# Editing a PDF Document

Tags: editing

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can you tell me a good pdf editor, which allow me full editing](https://superuser.com/questions/203943/can-you-tell-me-a-good-pdf-editor-which-allow-me-full-editing)

How can I edit PDF files for free. I do not have good internet speed. I do not need any online editing software. I need a 100% free software / Utility.

Comment: You'd get better answers if you were *very specific* about what editing tasks you need to accomplish.

Comment: This should be asked at: https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 2):

I just googled "Free PDF Editor" and this was the first result:
http://www.freepdfeditor.net/
may be what you need!

Comment: Let me google that for you!

Answer (score 1):

Don't know if it will fullfill your requirements but try [Inkscape](http://inkscape.org/)

Answer (score 0):

Try [PDF-XChange Viewer](http://www.docu-track.com/home/prod_user/PDF-XChange_Tools/pdfx_viewer).

Answer (score 0):

Already mentioned, Inkscape is a good suggestion for many tasks.

The [AbiWord](http://abisource.org) word processor (at least with all the import plugins installed) will import PDFs as Word Processing documents. There's [a plugin for OpenOffice](http://extensions.services.openoffice.org/project/pdfimport) which does the same. These are free.

You didn't say what operating system you were using, but there's the linux program [pdfedit](http://sourceforge.net/projects/pdfedit/) which might help. (You could always run linux virtually or through a live CD if need be, though with old hardware you should consider switching over to linux completely.)

Depending on what kinds of edits you need, [jPDFTweak](http://jpdftweak.sourceforge.net/) might work.